# Powershell exist local user ADSI

Tags: windows, powershell, local

I got the following code (working):

```
   #Import File
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\userImport\users.csv

# Setting data
$compname = hostname
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$compname" 
$userGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Users,Group"

# Loop to add all users
$Users | %  { 

    # Create user itself
    $createUser = $computer.Create("User",$_.userid)

    # Set password (print1!)
    $createUser.SetPassword($_.password)
    $createUser.SetInfo()

    # Create extra data
    $createUser.Description = "Import via powershell"
    $createUser.FullName = $_.'full name'
    $createUser.SetInfo()

    # Set standard flags (Password expire / Password change / Account disabled)
    $createUser.UserFlags = 64 + 65536 # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    $createUser.SetInfo()

    # Adduser to standard user group ("SERVER02\Users")
    $userGroup.Add($createUser.Path)

    # Show that user X as been added
    $username = $_.'full name'
    echo "User  $username added"
}
```

But how is possible to build an check if the user already exists?
I can not really find anything on the web :x

Comment: Already Exists in the group or as local user?

Comment: If the user already exists as local user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   #Import File
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\userImport\users.csv

# Setting data
$compname = hostname
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$compname" 
$userGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Users,Group"

$localUsers = $computer.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}  |  % {$_.name[0].ToString()}

# Loop to add all users
$Users | %  { 

    if($localUsers -NotContains $_.userID)
    {
      ... do your job here....
    }
    else
    {
      write-host "User $($_.userID) already exists"
    }
}
```

Comment: "user @{Full Name=P. Reichardt; userid=paj.Reichardt; Password=xxx}.userid does not exist." is what I get back with your script when I check with $_.userid

#Import File
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\userImport\userTest.csv

# Loop to add all users
$Users | %  { 

 $localUsers = $computer.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}  | % {$_.name[0].ToString()} 
 if ($localUsers -NotContains $_.userid) {
  write-host  "user $_.userid does not exist."
 }
 else {
  write-host "user $_.userid already exists."
 }
}

Comment: @PatrickRennings Edited my answer with variable expansion correctly set!

Comment: $_.userid is now filled with a large line: user @{Full Name=P. Reichardt; userid=paj.Reichardt; Password=xxx}.userid does not exist"

Comment: @PatrickRennings I've test it with a .csv with 3 columns and one named column as userID that has the account name and it works. Try cut&paste my code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, the ADSI interface seems to be broken in Windows 8.1.  here's my workaround:

```
if (& net users | select-string "UserName") {
    #  user exists
} else {
    #  user not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static `Exists` function of ADSI to check if an user exists:

```
[ADSI]::Exists('WinNT://./username')
```

But take note of this: [[ADSI]::Exists throws an exception instead of returning False](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10757316/932282)